# Verification of the existence of an inverse in a group

Tags: group-theory

In a group $(G,*)$ with neutral element $e$, does the relation $x*y=e$ imply $y*x=e$? i think it is true. Indeed, $y*x=y*(x*y)*x=(y*x)*(y*x)$ hence $(y*x)^n=y*x$ for each $n\geq 2$ which is true only if $y*x=e$. Is this correct? If yes, then to verify the existence of an inverse it suffices to verify only one of the two products is equal to $e$.

Comment: when you reach $y*x = y*x*y*x$ you could just simplify by $y*x$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of this will rely fundamentally on the fact that $*$ is an associative operation, and that a right-identity and right-inverses inverses exist.

Now, as you've seen, $$\begin{align}(y*x)*(y*x) &= \bigl((y*x)*y\bigr)*x &\text{[assoc.]}\\ &= \bigl(y*(x*y)\bigr)*x &\text{[assoc.]}\\ &= (y*e)*x &\text{[}x*y=e\text{]}\\ &= y*x & \text{[ident.]}\end{align}$$ so $$\begin{align}e &= (y*x)*(y*x)^{-1}\\ &= \bigl((y*x)*(y*x)\bigr)*(y*x)^{-1} &\text{[above work]}\\ &= (y*x)*\bigl((y*x)*(y*x)^{-1}\bigr) & \text{[assoc.]}\\ &= (y*x)*e &\text{[inv.]}\\ &= y*x, & \text{[ident.]}\end{align}$$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the step where you go from $(y * x)^n = y * x$ for each $n \geq 2$ to $y * x = e$ needs some reasoning.

However, from $y * x = (y * x) * (y * x)$ you can immediately get $y * x = e$ by the following proposition.

**Proposition.** Let $g$ be an idempotent element of some group $G$, i.e., $gg = g$. Then $g = e$.

**Proof.** $g = ge = g(g g^{-1}) = (gg) g^{-1} = g g^{-1} = e$.